# regarding Question not to installl app in android studio

Tags: java, android

How to restrict our application not to install in an emulator in Android Studio or any other emulator in Android Studio?

Comment: You can't do that.

Answer (score -1):

In general, there are three ways to bypass an emulator check:
Modify the app and remove the emulator check.
Modify the emulator so that it pretends to be a real device.
Modify the system calls the app does for detecting it is running on an emulator

Comment: Sure, but that won't prevent installation.